# Como classificar uma coluna de arquivo.csv sem usar funções de sort do PHP?

Tags: php, array, funções, csv, classificação

preciso da ajuda de vocês para concluir uma atividade da faculdade. Tenho que ordenar as linhas de um arquivo.csv de acordo com uma das colunas e exibir o resultado. Poderia usar o `array_multisort`, mas preciso escrevê-lo através de uma função criada por mim mesmo.
Obs: Não quero alterar o arquivo original, apenas manipulá-lo, sem usar as funções de sort do PHP. Quero criar a minha própria função para fazer isso.
As colunas do meu arquivo são: Nome;Nome_mae;Cidade_nasc
Isso é o que eu quero, mas sem usar o `array_multiosrt`:

```
    <?php   
        $handle = fopen("Arquivo.csv", "r");
        $row = 0;
        while($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) {
            if ($row++ == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            $Arquivo[] = ['Nome' => $line[0],
            'Nome_mae' => $line[1], 'Cidade_nasc' => $line[2]];
        }

        $Matriz = $Arquivo;

        foreach ($Matriz as $key => $row){
            $Nome[$key] = $row['Nome'];
            $Nome_mae[$key] = $row['Nome_mae'];
            $Cidade_nasc[$key] = $row['Cidade_nasc'];
        }

        array_multisort($Nome, SORT_ASC, $Matriz);
        print_r($Matriz); #Imprime a Matriz por ordem alfabética dos Nomes

        foreach ($Matriz as $key => $row){
            $Nome[$key] = $row['Nome'];
            $Nome_mae[$key] = $row['Nome_mae'];
            $Cidade_nasc[$key] = $row['Cidade_nasc'];
        }

        array_multisort($Nome_mae, SORT_ASC, $Matriz);
        print_r($Matriz); #Imprime a Matriz por ordem alfabética dos nomes 
        das Mães

        foreach ($Matriz as $key => $row){
            $Nome[$key] = $row['Nome'];
            $Nome_mae[$key] = $row['Nome_mae'];
            $Cidade_nasc[$key] = $row['Cidade_nasc'];
        }

        array_multisort($Cidade_nasc, SORT_ASC, $Matriz);
        print_r($Matriz); #Imprime a Matriz por ordem alfabética das Cidades

        print_r($Arquivo); #Imprime a Matriz Original
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu criaria uma chave para `$Arquivo[]` com o valor que gostaria de usar como referência e depois usava `ksort()` ou `krsort()` para reordenar.

Por exemplo:

```
$handle = fopen("Arquivo.csv", "r");

$header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) {
    $Arquivo[$row['data']] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

ksort($Arquivo);
```

---

### Edit:

Existem soluções mais elegantes, mas a lógica é mais ou menos essa:

```
$arr = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
function mySort(array $input): array
{
    $output = [];
    $count = count($input);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            // grava a primeira entrada direto.
            $output[] = $input[$i];
        } elseif ($output[0] > $input[$i]) {
            // se a entrada for menor que o primeiro valor no array,
            // adiciona a entrada no inicio.
            array_unshift($output, $input[$i]);
        } elseif (end($output) < $input[$i]) {
            // se for maior adiciona no final.
            $output[] = $input[$i];
        } else {
            // varre o array procurando a posição no meio
            for ($v = 0; $v < count($output); $v++) {
                if ($input[$i] < $output[$v] && 
                    key_exists($v + 1, $output) &&
                    $input[$i] < $output[$v + 1]) 
                    {
                    // divide o array em dois
                    $start = array_slice($output, 0, $v);
                    $end = array_slice($output, $v);
                    $start[] = $input[$i];
                    // monta o array novamente
                    $output = array_merge($start, $end);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

var_dump(mySort($arr));
// array (size=5)
//     0 => int 1
//     1 => int 2
//     2 => int 3
//     3 => int 4
//     4 => int 5
```

Comment: Legal Bruno Chaves, essa é uma boa resposta, entretanto não resolve o meu problema, pois preciso ordenar criando a minha própria função, ou seja não usar as funções de ordenação da própria linguagem. (Tipo, uasort(), usort(), ksort()...)

Comment: Editei minha resposta com uma possível solução.

Comment: Opa, Bruno Chaves. Analisei a sua resposta, e não conseguir entender muito bem, não sei se é realmente o que eu queria, vou editar minha pergunta, e se for realmente o que eu queria, então você me explica, tá bom ?